# Conditional Expectation with binary expansions

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

[image]

I've proved the pairwise independent part, albeit very informally (basically amounted to proving half of 1/2 is 1/4), but I'm stuck where to start with the second part. Checking the two axioms of conditional expectations seems very unwieldy here, am I supposed to construct the conditional expectations as sums/series? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Prove and use the expression $$X=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}\mathbf 1_{A_n}$$

Comment: Ah yes of course. The earlier part of the question asked to prove the series version of Monotone Convergence Theorem for conditional expectations of non-negative random variables so this solves the entire problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I get the conditional expectation of X given f_n as 1_An/2^n + (1-2^-n)/2 is this correct? Sorry I can't type maths very well